# Using git underneath a perforce repository - an easy way to notify perforce of changes?

Tags: git, version-control, perforce

So,
I've been driven nuts enough by Perforce I'm now attempting to use a git repo beneath the covers.

My question is this:

When I'm futzing around with the files via my git repo, is there an easy/automatic way for me to keep track of these in perforce? I've looked into git hooks, and there doesn't seem to be one that when I commit a file to the git repo, it automatically opens the file for edit in perforce, so the perforce server knows about the changes. Let alone anything to do with moving the file around, which git recognizes automatically but perforce needs to be specifically told about.

I currently have perforce configured so that all files are writable, which makes things a lot easier when using things like emacs for editing.

Should I just be looking into git-p4? I had a few people say they were successfully using a git repo under the covers of another version control repo (perforce or otherwise).

Comment: I don't know about the perforce side, but shouldn't a post-commit hook be sufficient? It can tell what the commit contents were, and run whatever commands are needed to get perforce to do its thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meh, sounds like git post-commit hooks, checking the diff-tree and scripting madness are about the only good(?) answer I've heard.

Answer (score 3):

Do use git-p4, it's quite easy to use.

To set it up, first you need to enter all your files in P4, then you can do git p4 clone //my/p4/repo.

A good documentation for git-p4 can be found here: http://kb.perforce.com/article/1417/git-p4